# Singular countable nouns on its own without any article

Tags: articles

So the general rule is that an article, either definite or indefinite, must be used with any countable singular nouns.

We say 'a chair' or 'the chair', for example.

But I found some singular countable nouns without any article in these sentences.

palm tree:
**Tree** native to tropical regions; among its various species are date- and coconut-bearing kinds.

ractor:
**Motorized machine** used for operating farm equipment and tools.

container:
**Metal box** of standardized size for transporting cargo.

Are these sentences correct or not?

Comment: Did you find these sentences in a dictionary or glossary? If so, then you're looking at examples of what is called "headline English." Places where space is at a premium -- dictionaries, instruction manuals, signs, and (of course) headlines often drop words to save space. You wouldn't do that in conversation or other kinds of text. (And I'll bet the **Motorized machine** is a **t**ractor.)

Comment: @user105719 Thank you so much!;DDDD